# Shopware 6 SwagPayPal Default configuration is not working

Tags: paypal, shopware

I am using shopware 6 and install plugin SwagPayPal. On Default Configuration page of plugin i added client_id and client secret key but after that i am getting like this

```
The webhook could not be saved. The following errors occurred:
Client error: `POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks` 
resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","message":"Invalid data provided","debug_id":"XXXXXX","information_link":"https://deve (truncated...)
```

can anyone help me here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working in a local environment that isn't reachable for the paypal servers, you will get this error every time. But only the webhook won't work, everything else will work and you can test the integration. It should be no problem for testing.